# glob() foreach not working in IE11, works in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, internet-explorer, cycle2

I am very confused! Here's the site I'm working on: http://209.200.104.187/

I am using the Cycle2 plugin for jQuery and CodeIgniter.

In Chrome, it looks like this: 
[image: Notice the image fader...]

There is a cycler behind the main content. It works for me in Chrome, but not in IE11. Furthermore, my client says it is not working in their chrome browser.

The way I generate the image cycler is like this:

```
<?php if(@$home_header == 1): ?> 
  <div id="slideshow" class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-pause-on-hover="false" 
       data-cycle-speed="3000">
  <?php
    $slides = glob('assets/images/home/background/'.'*.jpg'); 
    foreach($slides as $s) { 
      echo '<img src="'.$s.'" />'; 
    } 
  ?> 
  </div> 
<?php endif; ?>
```

I checked the IE11 source code and there are no images, but there IS `<div id="slideshow"></div>`. It just has an empty `<div>`.

MOREOVER, if I try to output straight HTML `<img/>` tags, IE11 is NOT showing them. Just for debugging purposes, I tried to put some images inside `#slideshow`, and they didn't appear in IE, even when I cleared the cache and refreshed.

I'm very confused because the debugging images show up immediately in Chrome. But never in IE.

Any ideas why IE is behaving so strangely? I am not using jQuery to initiate the Cycle2 plugin, I'm using `data-` attributes.

I tried it with jQuery initialization instead and that didn't work either.

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache? Those elements are being rendered by the server so they should appear regardless of the browser.

Comment: Please don't link to resources that could soon go offline. If at all possible, help us prevent link-rot on Stack Overflow. Also, please check your developer tools' console. I'm seeing quite a bit of output in Chrome, suggesting a failure to load key resources.

Comment: Yes, my first steps were to check the console and clear the cache, still to no avail. In IE11, the `#slideshow` div is not even rendering the data- attributes or the image tags. I do not see any output in Chrome's dev console. What sort of things suggest failure to load resources?